# Automatically center the content of a program while scaling the window with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, center, fxml, autoscaling

Im new to JavaFX and have to program a software for my school project.

If my program is running i can scale the window as usual. The whole content in the window stays at the position which i gave them.
Now i would like to center the whole content of the program while I'm scaling the open window.

It should work like the `margin:auto` in CSS where the container or pane is always in the middle of the window, doesn't matter what size the window has.

I am using FXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `VBox` as the root container of your `Scene`, and set the aligment of the `VBox` to `CENTER`.

```
VBox vBox = new VBox();
vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,400,400);
```

For more detailed description, please read this question:
[How do I center JavaFX controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169445/how-do-i-center-javafx-controls)